# Manual mock React-Intl with Jest to have snapshot testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, react-intl

I have been struggling mocking [React-Intl library](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl) with [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/manual-mocks.html) because I'm having this error when I run tests:

```
Invariant Violation: [React Intl] Could not find required `intl` object. <IntlProvider> needs to exist in the component ancestry.
```

The [documentation](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/Testing-with-React-Intl#jest-mock) of this library says that we have to create a folder in root project called `__Mocks__` and then add this file:

```
// ./__mocks__/react-intl.js
import React from 'react';
const Intl = require.requireActual('react-intl');

// Here goes intl context injected into component, feel free to extend
const intl = {
  formatMessage: ({defaultMessage}) => defaultMessage
};

Intl.injectIntl = (Node) => (props) => <Node {...props} intl={intl}/>;

module.exports = Intl;
```

But nothing happens.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After hours looking in it, I found that what I needed to change was the way I was requiring `react-intl` package. So, I changed that line:

```
const Intl = require.requireActual('react-intl');
```

to that:

```
const Intl = jest.genMockFromModule('react-intl');
```

So the final file looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
const Intl = jest.genMockFromModule('react-intl'); // <-- This is the change

const intl = {
  formatMessage: ({defaultMessage}) => defaultMessage
};

Intl.injectIntl = (Node) => (props) => <Node {...props} intl={intl}/>;

module.exports = Intl;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You have to use ```const Intl = jest.genMockFromModule('react-intl');```

Comment: How do you get Jsx elements to work with the module.js file? Jest is failing to run the tests because of unknown character '<'